# Why was my mod flag to migrate a question declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, migration

I flagged this question for migration to GIS.SE yesterday:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531573/shapefile-georeferencing-using-arcmap-10-2-2

It has naught to do with programming, it is an issue which is well known how to do/solve within Geographic Information Systems. There was no reason for the decline of my flag; I'd expected at least a "This question is considered too low quality for migration". It's a bit vague, admittedly, but on GIS.SE they'll know what he's talking about and ask the correct clarification.

Comment: Why are you asking for clarification if you *already know* why the flag was declined?  (Namely that the question isn't a quality question.)

Comment: Because to non-GIS users it's very unclear, to GIS users it's rather clear, they just need to know the state of his shapefile to help him in minutes

Comment: The fact that you're admitting that the question doesn't currently contain enough information to be answerable just proves my point.

Comment: @Servy so I should ask for clarification here and *then*  vote to migrate?

Comment: @Adriaan You should only be asking for high quality questions to be migrated.

Comment: Don't try to polish turds when editing questions, and don't try to move garbage when trying to migrate. Trash is trash, no matter where it is placed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Servy notes, the official SE policy is "don't migrate crap."

In my experience, it's actually quite rare for flagging a question for migration to be the optimal choice:

- If the question is new and has no answers yet, it's better to close it as off-topic and tell the asker to repost it on the proper site (as happened with your example question).  This avoids wasting ♦ moderator time on things that the community (and the OP) can take care of.
- Conversely, if the question is older than 60 days, then [it *cannot* be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days), not even by ♦ mods.  Thus, there is no point in flagging such questions.  Also, migrating questions that *do* have answers is also [officially discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) (although not actually prevented by the software).
- In particular, if the question already has correct answers (and the answers aren't themselves blatantly off-topic), that's a sign that it may not be completely off-topic after all.  In such cases, it may be better to just edit the question to remove the off-topic parts, leaving a valid on-topic question.
- In any case, it's quite possible for a question to be (more or less) on topic at multiple SE sites.  Such questions should *not* be migrated.
- Finally, if the question is heavily downvoted, has poor spelling and/or grammar, or otherwise appears to be of low quality at a glance, moderators are likely to decline the migration, no matter how much you may think that there's a pearl of a question hiding under the dirt.

So the "sweet spot" for migration is a something like relatively new (but not brand new) question that is clearly written and generally perfect in every way, *except* for being *obviously* on the wrong site.  It should also have at least one good answer, but the answer should *also* obviously belong on another site.  And ideally, despite being blatantly off-topic, it shouldn't be too heavily downvoted (although migration does [reset negative scores to zero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/reset-post-score-to-0-on-migration) nowadays), but also [not too heavily upvoted, either](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions).

Honestly, there just aren't a lot of questions that meet all those contradictory requirements.

Of course, you may be lucky, and get a sympathetic mod that will migrate the question even though it's not *that* awesome, or even though it *might* be marginally on-topic at its current site too, or even though the OP *could* just repost it.  To maximize your odds of success, you may, before flagging, wish to do the following*:

- Copyedit the question, fixing any spelling and grammar errors and making sure the general structure of the question is clear and to the point.  Do *not* wait to do this until after the migration!

  Generally, you should edit the question *as if it was already on the target site*, so that it will be obviously on-topic when migrated.  However, *don't* edit a marginally on-topic question so as to make it off-topic on the current site — there's a fine line to tread here.  Also resist the temptation to use features (like MathJax) that aren't actually enabled on the source site. ;-)
- Leave a comment on the question, stating that you think it's off-topic on this site, but would be a good question on <site X>, and that you've flagged / will be flagging it for migration.  Besides being a useful pointer for the OP, in case the migration is declined, such a comment may also discourage downvotes on the question, and lets other users express their support for the migration by upvoting your comment.
- Make *sure* that the question actually would be a good fit for the target site.  You may wish to visit the target site's chat room and *ask if they want the question* before flagging it for migration.
- *If* the question has a low score, consider upvoting it.
- If you can cast close votes, vote to close the question as off-topic.

Finally, when casting the flag, do explain any specific reasons you may have for thinking that the question needs migration.  If you've already asked the folks at the target site if they want it, include a chat permalink.

One thing I don't really have enough data on is whether, if you can answer the question yourself, it's better to do so before it's migrated.  On one hand, SE policy does discourage migrating answered questions; on the other hand, posting an answer does serve as *prima facie* evidence that the question *is* answerable, and may also demonstrate that the essence of the answer (and thus, by extension, of the question) is outside the scope of the site.

In any case, if you *could* answer the question, but for some reason don't wish to do so before migration (e.g. because your answer really needs a feature like MathJax that the current site doesn't have), do make sure to note this in your flag, and/or in your comment on the question.  FWIW, I have successfully flagged several questions for migration that I'd also answered myself, so at least it's not a definite no-no.

<sup>*) Note that these suggestions are all merely personal opinions based on my experience as a (formerly) active migration flagger.  They should not be taken to reflect official SE policy in any way, except by coincidence.</sup>

---

**Ps.** One more thing I forgot to mention: What if you really think that a particular question would be a *great* addition to another SE site, but it can't or won't be migrated for some reason?  Maybe it's too old to migrate, maybe it's actually on topic at both sites, or maybe you went with the "close and ask OP to repost" route, but the OP has vanished?

In all these cases, there's a simple solution: **Ask the question yourself**, in your own words, on the other site.

Although users are discouraged from *simultaneously* asking the same question on multiple SE sites (to avoid wasting community effort), it's [perfectly fine](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) to have [essentially similar questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates) on [different sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172307/duplicate-questions-on-other-se-sites).  Of course, where needed, you *should* reword the question to better suit the target site, and you definitely should also include a link back to the original question, both for clarity and attribution, and to provide access to any existing answers there.

This works particularly well if you can also provide a good, definitive answer to the question at the same time.  If the original question already *has* a good answer, you may also wish to post an answer on the other site that links to and briefly summarizes it.  (Technically, since all content on SE is [CC-By-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) licensed, you could even copy the original answer verbatim, *provided that* you [attribute it properly](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).  If you do that, it's usually considered good form to mark the copied answer as Community Wiki, so that you won't gain "undeserved" rep from it.)

Comment: Thanks for the extensive explanation. I am slightly familiar with GIS, but I'd have to reread some lecture notes to be able to actually answer his question, though that shouldn't take more than an hour. Thanks for showing there are still people willing to help instead of terminating everything that's outside their backyard.

Answer (score 11):

We don't migrate crap.  We only migrate high quality content that will be a great addition to the target site *as the question sits*.

This question doesn't meet that criteria.