# Should I mod flag users who repeatedly answer a question and then vote to close it?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I will periodically see high-rep power users on certain tags answer an off-topic question, and then vote to close it.

The community (and mod/CW) consensus is that [we shouldn't answer off topic questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270420/2415822).

I generally add a comment on these answers that the question should be closed, or to not answer duplicates.  Sometimes, the answer is deleted by the owner.  Other times, it is acceped and sticks around.

Is this repeated behavior a flaggable offense?  How "frequent" would warrant a flag?  I don't want to go on a witch hunt, but I don't want power users to be setting a bad example by answering off-topic questions.

Comment: *"I will periodically see high-rep power users on certain tags answer an off-topic question, and then vote to close it."* - I've seen this happen quite a few times and them posting answers for them and closing the question with a gold tag. I then had one guy argue my reopening the question. Oddly enough when I flagged the reopen/question, it was declined; this is quite questionable. Plus, what they're actually doing is holding a monopoly which isn't fair at all and I've discussed this a few times before with those in question and others who weren't part of the guilty parties.

Comment: Related: [Is the How to Answer article's section on only answering well-asked questions advice or site policy?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348705/is-the-how-to-answer-articles-section-on-only-answering-well-asked-questions-ad)

Comment: This happens accidentally more than you're allowing for. There are three problems: (1) voting to close does not close, unless you use the dupehammer, so the question still needs answering; (2) voting to close prevents converting to dupehammer later when you discover the dupe; (3) an accepted answer cannot be deleted. So, you say I'm gaming the system, but I would argue that the system is gaming me. If I had stronger powers (to close, to convert to dupehammer, to delete an accepted answer) I wouldn't have this problem. Also, answering a question does not absolve me of my duty to vote to close.

Comment: @matt 1. Who says this is about you?  2. `voting to close does not close, unless you use the dupehammer, so the question still needs answering;` an off-topic question does not need answering, it needs to be closed.  3. `voting to close prevents converting to dupehammer later when you discover the dupe;` you can always go to chat (in places like the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)) for help with closing a question as a duplicate which you've already voted to close for a different reason.

Comment: I'm using "me" in a role-playing sense.

Comment: And I should add (4) SO has a strong speed component, so things happen in a rush and I can end up stumbling over my own feet. The point is that the situation you describe is often not a tactic but a trap. (Also, you may not be taking into account the many times I _do_ write an answer, then delete it and vote to close instead.)

Comment: @matt: Re (1): ["*Closing is a democratic voting process where the community identifies questions that duplicate existing content, are unreasonable to answer in their current state, or do not belong on the site.*"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) – Or, as BoltClock said below: *"By doing that (answering questions and then voting to close them), you're sending the asker a mixed signal. The asker then doesn't know if their question was on-topic or off-topic, or if their question was clear (enough for you to answer) or unclear."*

Comment: @JAL: As I understand it from https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161861, close votes are anonymous until the question is actually closed (which may never happen). So while I agree that one should not VTC *and* answer, detecting these situations is not always possible.

Comment: @JAL An example of a Question where answers were posted to OP, and following edit of the Question a "close" vote was cast; the edited text of the Question being even less clear than than OP https://stackoverflow.com/q/46392679/; another example of a Question which is not immediately clear https://stackoverflow.com/q/45560072/, though each discrete Question still has a viable Answer. The scope of possibilities relevant to questions and answers in the universe is not exclusively linear, as some would-be hardliners might suggest. If concepts were only linear we would not have quantum mechanics.

Comment: @JAL _"1. If a (logical or axiomatic formal) system is consistent, it cannot be complete.
2. The consistency of axioms cannot be proved within their own system."_ -Kurt Godel

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Yes, if there's a pattern and both actions are in "same" time frame, flag'em!

We have trusted users with domain knowledge that we let hammer questions as  duplicates to other questions so that SO gets better for future users.

Answering a question and then hammering as a duplicate (in same time frame) is a clear misuse of the system and against the whole idea of duplicating questions (that is to collect all good answers in one place). It also has an ugly gamification part in the way it blocks other users from answering.

If you answer and then go *"heck this is a duplicate"*, you should either [move your answer to the duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) or if it is of no additional use just **delete it**.

The same discussion is valid for any other close vote reason (even if I would be more tolerant in some other cases, the pattern needs to be consistent). That said, if you close vote, you state that the question can not or should not be answered, it has to be improved first.

**You answer or you close it, you don't do both!**

<sup><sup>Well you can, but since you are well aware that we are not helping single OP but trying to create a useful Q/A for programmers, it's fairly obvious that you care more about your own reputation points than this common community objective. Also do note that my answer is related to "same" time frame, finding a year old question you have answered and closing it, instead I would consider a clean up effort.</sup></sup>

Comment: *darn, I don't have gold badge in [discussion]*

Comment: _"You answer or you close it, you can't do both!"_ That is patently false. You can do whatever you decide to do at that moment in time.

Comment: @guest271314 sure and I did add a footnote, the statement was naturally related to what I consider best for the community. If you think power users should first answer and then dupe close you are free to down vote and post your own answer why you think this is a good solution.

Comment: @guest271314 you can do whatever you want, but that doesn't mean that your actions are constructive.

Comment: @JAL Will be the judge of what is "constructive" for self. The peer pressure culture at SO, and especially meta SO, is more palpable that a room full of middle schoolers. The box is rigid and impenetrable. Don't encourage a whistleblower culture. That is ridiculous. Engage with the individual user yourself. The mod squad are not perfect either, so why go rat to them? Talk directly to the person yourself.

Comment: @guest271314 `Talk directly to the person yourself.` you must have missed the part of my question that says I leave a comment on these answers.

Comment: @JAL Then that is all you can do. What do you expect mod squad to do? Have answered questions and voted to close the question. So what?

Comment: *constructive for self?, rat to them?, engage with individual?, ooh what platform do we use for this?, twitter?*

Comment: @PetterFriberg No, have probably less than ten *witter posts. That is just basic reality. Don't encourage whistleblower culture. Uncle mod squad will do what exactly? Help create a better peer-pressure room for you to pat each others' backs. Engage the user themselves.

Comment: what should mods do?, just delete the answer and let the crap roomba?, how about that?

Comment: That is not a solution. _You_ can move on to a different Question. Who are you to judge what is "crap". And if you do jusge it as "crap", so what? For some the whistleblower, peer-pressure, our "community" culture slogans is "crap". Get off your high and might horse. No question is different from any other question or answer. If neither interest you, move on to one that does. Judging the content of a question or answer is ok. Engage that user, not mod squad, who have their own issues.

Comment: no I flag (I rat to mods) NAA, plagiarism, vandalism and other misuse on SO, not sure it's "constructive for self" but I hope for future users to avoid that they need to dig through all the repzz hunting mess.

Comment: Then propose elimination of "rep" altogether. That would negate the entire premise of "downvote", "upvote", etc. Interesting you mention nothing of the censorship of this users' Answer by mod squad at the present Question.

Comment: Jon would kill me ;), but the problem is not the repz in itself, the problem is people getting high on it, just flag the mess and let the modz clean it up.   *censorship of this users?*

Comment: The question was about VTC, not dupe hammer. The latter would definitely be an abuse. The former not so much; I've done it a few times.

Comment: @guest271314: Enforcing quality and behavior standards is not *censorship*. The site has guidelines, and is entitled to enforce compliance with those guidelines. There is no *free speech is guaranteed* at privately-owned web sites. SO has the absolute right to decide what is (and is not) appropriate content and conduct for this site. The fact they openly encourage user participation in developing those guidelines does not mean they cannot make their own decisions in that regard.

Comment: It's not always a dupe hammer closure. I know of at least one extremely high rep user who frequently votes to close a question as off-topic or low quality or unclear while at the same time posting an answer and getting upvotes before the question is closed and the close vote apparent.

Comment: @miken32: By doing that (answering questions and then voting to close them), you're sending the asker a mixed signal. The asker then doesn't know if their question was on-topic or off-topic, or if their question was clear (enough for you to answer) or unclear.

Comment: There is [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/712185) by rene that lists the people who dupe-hammer after answering. [(source)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355334/disable-hammering-via-voting-to-close-if-you-have-answered-the-question#comment505902_355334)

Comment: @guest271314 Okay, so, say we eliminate rep and site guidelines. Do you really think SO will function under anarchy? Before you respond, look carefully at the stream of mismanaged websites that necessitated the creation of SO. How do you suggest we avoid their fate if we let this become another unmoderated forum?

Comment: @forresthopkinsa It's going to be [quite a while](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2801559/guest271314) before guest271314 can respond.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Wow, that's poetic

Comment: @KenWhite You are correct in that stackoverflow.com ("SO") owners and its agents have selectively decided when or when not to follow any supposed "guidelines"; from posting [completely off-topic political stump speeches](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342440); refusing to answer questions [\[Awaiting answer\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341058) over eight months after SO disclosed SO user PII in HTML; [more off-topic political stump speeches](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342903/); to allowing [browser fingerprinting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335956) SO visitors to sell ads.

Comment: @guest271314: I guess if you don't like the way SO handles things, you're always free to go somewhere else.

Comment: @KenWhite The previous comment is not intended to convey a "like" or "don't like". When you mention "guidelines" as if supposed "standards" are set from the top down, you neglected to mention when SO decided not to follow its own, or for that matter, any "standards" or "guidelines". Users can draw their own conclusions as to the facts concerning the premise of purported SO standards or guidelines.

Comment: @forresthopkinsa Already made the suggestion at an Answer, which was deleted. The board can take care of itself.

Answer (score 21):

I would not penalise those who actually **use the hammer**, redirecting to a question with better in-depth answers - whether they initially posted an answer or not. Instead I would very much want to flag all those with scores in thousands or *tens* of thousands in the relevant tag, who *never* use the hammer on obvious duplicates.

Also, it is impossible to actually **self-remove** an answer if it has been accepted, but even if your answer got accepted, then later find a perfect target, it should never be too late to do the right thing.

---

Disclaimer: I thought I might have done this sometimes myself - and it was true; according to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/712185) I have hammered a question that I have also answered to - a grand total of 4 times; however to my defence there were on average 4 answers to the questions at that time.

Comment: You can always gather a friendly mob of 20k users who can remove the blemish that is your accepted answer from the beautiful face of Stack Overflow.

Comment: With dupes, it can be quite appropriate to write a short answer that summarises the key info at the dupe target, or helps a new coder to understand how to apply that info. But often that can be done in a comment rather than a full answer. However, this meta question is _not_ about dupes: it's about high rep members who regularly answer _off-topic_ questions which they also close vote, and that's quite a different scenario in my book: I can't see a valid reason to do that.

Comment: OTOH, I must confess that when I close-vote resource requests I may post a helpful suggestion (possibly including a link) in a comment if I feel that the OP sincerely wants to learn and they aren't just being a HV.

Comment: @PM2Ring The question also mentions duplicates: "I generally add a comment [...] to not answer duplicates.[...]" and Petter's answer directs the talk towards hammer-wielding goldbadgers

Comment: Ok, but I think the primary concern here is in regard to off-topic questions. Sure, there is a tendency to lump dupes in with off-topic questions, but that's not really fair: dupe questions aren't intrinsically bad, we want them closed because we generally don't want the answers to dupe questions scattered all over the place. And that's because that makes them hard to find, can lead to dupe answers, and stops the answers from competing properly with each other for votes.

Comment: I guess there's also the possibility that someone will answer a bad / off-topic question and then not merely close-vote it, but dupe-hammer it (possibly to some ancient relic). I can't bring any examples to mind, but I'm pretty sure I've seen it happen.

Comment: Interesting, according to that query I have never gold hammered a question I answered. There goes the premise of my own answer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No, you’re just somewhere in the bottom of the result list and the list happens to be lazily rendered, so you cannot search properly with your browser. You have a result row with `6 / 3 / 4` (whatever those columns are actually supposed to mean).

Answer (score 18):

I occasionally do this (not closing as off-topic, but voting as duplicate), and you seem to assume bad intent where there might be none.

For example, sometimes I answer a question as I couldn't find an immediate duplicate at that time. Then after posting the initial answer, I want to add additional info for further clarification or writing the answer makes me think of better search terms, and then I find a duplicate. I then proceed to gold-hammer the question as duplicate and move on. I will not remove my answer, because it does answer the question.

If you assume this behavior is 'rep hunting', then you are wrong, because as soon as a question is closed as duplicate, the answers will usually not attract any more up votes, nor will they usually attract an accept vote.

Now, if a user does this so often that it becomes a clear pattern, you might want to notify a mod. But even then, assuming bad intent is wrong IMHO.

Comment: [I was right!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355334/disable-hammering-via-voting-to-close-if-you-have-answered-the-question#comment505870_355334)

Comment: @BoltClock Hah, I could almost copy this answer one-on-one to that ;)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I also regularly answer a question only for *another* user to find a duplicate, in which case if I agree with the duplicate I'll just hammer it in.

Comment: Mark I can understand if you go back to old answer and decide to close it as duplicate (that you did not found when you wrote the answer), but if at same time that you answer, it is incorrect (you should answer on the dupe), you are scattering answer around making it harder for future users to find good answer and sending an ugly signal to new users (I answer, then I dupe, haa now it's only my answer on question). Probably it's better for internet and the future of SO to have some discipline and just delete the answer if it does not bring anything new.

Comment: I have to agree with @Petter on this.  If it's different enough from the dup-target that you can't explain in a couple comments what makes this a special case or alternate version of the linked duplicate(s), you should leave the question open and post an answer that answers the specific question, and links to the other questions and/or answers for background.

Comment: @PeterCordes that would be perfectly fine for me, if you answer, you answer, so you should not start closing (that has no sense, it's only confusing for new user and original OP), if you think it's nice to have a link to a related posted add it in answer or in a comment as related.

Comment: I firmly agree with @BoltClock and mark and very much disagree with JAL on this proposal.

Comment: How do [both](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355335/2288578) [versions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355336/2288578) of this answer have exactly 11 votes each? They must be connected through some magical link :P

Comment: @PetterFriberg If I find the duplicate while writing the answer, I will close as duplicate and not post the answer. But if I already posted the answer, I will leave it in place: it helps the OP.

Comment: It would help the OP as well if you moved your answer to the dupe target, or converted it to a comment or two. And you are not helping the OP to ask better questions, you are training them to research isn't all that important and that someone will answer their dupe questions anyway. And again, _helping_ (as in solving their problem) the OP is not the target. [SO is not a helpdesk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal). The target is having a better quality knowledge repository.

Comment: @Petter I am skeptical that scattering answers really has any negative effects. The real problem occurs if the questions are never linked -- not only do visitors not benefit from the full set of answers, but answerers and later editors don't benefit from each other (e.g., if one of them catches a subtlety that others miss). I don't really buy into the dogma that the ideal Q&A will have all dupes collapsed into one, nor do I believe such an ideal could ever be approached. Per Jeff Atwood: "it’s OK for duplicate questions to have duplicate answers."

Comment: @Frank let me continue to quote Jeff *"What we want is on the order of 4 or 5 similar-but-not-quite-the-same duplicates to cover all possible search terms and common permutations of the question. It is also OK for these duplicates to have their own answers so people who find them don’t have to click yet again to get to a good answer."* I think this issue can simple be avoid, if you are in 4-5 similar area is to link the question in answer or in a comment under question. There is no need if similar that you also close as dupe, link it and let other answer the similar one.

Comment: *however by now normally we are more in the 100-1K similar area....*, I also answered yesterday "Why do I get java.lang.NoSuchMethodError", since it had to do with a particular library. Hence I felt it could be useful for this particolar library to have info what you need to do, but answering I'm also saying that the answers on the duplicate is not what you are searching for, hence I don't vote as duplicate.

Comment: I agree that answering and then voting to close as a duplicate is not really a problem, but answering and then voting to close as off-topic is, since off-topic questions should't be answered. I've seen a user answer a Stack Overflow question that isn't about programming ([this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYsxE.png)). I don't think the user voted to close that question, but anyway, questions like that shouldn't be answered.

Answer (score 10):

I created the [following SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/712989/duplicate-hammers-where-the-hammerer-has-a-non-deleted-answer) to get a list of such active questions that were

- dupe hammered
- the hammerer has an active answer
- hammerer is still active
- the hammer was used in the past year

  ```
   select hc.UserId [User Link], u.displayname, p.id, p.title, answers.score
   from PostHistory hc
   inner join posts p on hc.postid=p.id
   inner join posts answers on answers.parentid=p.id and hc.userid=answers.owneruserid
   inner join users u on hc.userid=u.id
   where hc.PostHistoryTypeId=10
   and hc.Comment like '101%'
   and hc.Text like '%BindingReason":{"GoldTagBadge%'
   and hc.CreationDate > getdate()-365
  ```

Based on the results, there are quite a few users where such an activity is a recurring pattern. I include here the top 10 users based on the count of such closures. I also included the sum of votes on these answers:

```
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|     User Name      |   Sum of Votes    | Number of Questions |
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| Günter Zöchbauer   |               297 |                  77 |
| T.J. Crowder       |               170 |                  62 |
| Martijn Pieters    |               251 |                  45 |
| Charles Duffy      |                49 |                  45 |
| Michael_B          |               111 |                  39 |
| EJP                |                65 |                  37 |
| matt               |                32 |                  36 |
| Barmar             |                23 |                  28 |
| Wiktor Stribiżew   |                28 |                  26 |
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

It's up to the moderators what they do with this information (Martijn is in the top ten and BoltClock also had 6 such instances).

Comment: Nice but probably time been answering and duplicating should be consider, duplicating an old question years after (in a clean up effort) is different from answering and then duplicating or close voting for other reason.

Comment: Is a similar list possible for questions that were voted to close as unclear or off-topic and answered by the same user?

Comment: @PetterFriberg yep, the query can be refined further. I was not thinking about the time because even as part of a cleanup operation, the own answer could have been removed. I was more thinking along the lines where the answer was accepted **before** the question was duped. In this case the hammerer cannot delete the answer even if he wanted to.

Comment: @MartinR you can probably create a similar list for those cases as well. However, dupe hammer is an unilateral action, while closing the question via any other reason requires 4 other users' consent (unless you are a diamond moderator, obviously).

Comment: I've tweaked your query to only show closures which happened within two weeks of the answer, and only those which weren't later reopened by the same user: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/713470/duplicate-hammers-where-the-hammerer-has-a-non-deleted-answer and the resulting table: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/713469/duplicate-hammers-where-the-hammerer-has-a-non-deleted-answer

Comment: @MartinR: Sure, e.g. [like this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/714258/top-users-who-answered-and-voted-to-close-excluding-dupes). I'm counting all non-dupe closes, but you can exclude [other close reason types](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678) by editing the `Comment not in (...)` condition. Note that SEDE doesn't expose individual close votes, so the query only relies on the reported consensus reason; some of those users might've voted to close some of those questions as dupes, but were overridden by other voters. Or vice versa.

Comment: I don't know what the query does, but I do **NOT** answer off-topic questions and then close them as duplicates. I actually stopped answering duplicates (as I understand them) when I got 45K rep (years ago). I only reopen and then answer, but never answer and then close as dupes. I have seen others doing that from your list though.

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, I wanted to see how many times I'd done this myself in the past, and for what reasons, so I wrote [an SEDE query to find posts one has both answered and closed](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/713689/questions-ive-answered-and-closed).

(I also made [a version that searches all Stack Exchange sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/space/query/713960/questions-ive-answered-and-closed-on-all-se-sites) based on your network account ID.)

---

[Running the query against my user ID on SO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/713689/questions-ive-answered-and-closed?UserId=411022), I got eight results:

1. [Why should a salt have the same length as the hashed value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064227/why-should-a-salt-have-the-same-length-as-the-hashed-value) is borderline off-topic, but would've been a good question for [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) or [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).  I answered and suggested migration in comments, which the OP agreed with, but apparently my mod flag requestion migration was never acted on (although it was marked as helpful).  By now, the question is far too old to migrate.
2. [1357133639816 milliseconds conversion in PHP 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145101/1357133639816-milliseconds-conversion-in-php-5-3) is a duplicate as asked, but if the OP tried to apply the answers from the older question directly, they wouldn't get the output they expect due to time zone issues.  My answer points to the dupe, and also describes how to deal with the time zone issue.  I should probably move my answer to the dupe, or at least post an equivalent answer there.
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413524/how-to-convert-byte-array-into-string-in-java According to the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14413524/timeline), I answered an early version of this question, but the answer didn't satisfy the OP and it turned out that their real problem was something other than what they were asking about.  As my answer no longer even fits the edited title of the question, I should probably just delete it and let the [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) take care of the question.
4. [Using of Wikipedia API with Rest Clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407479/using-of-wikipedia-api-with-rest-clients) Answered, found a dupe immediately afterwards, marked my answer as [Community Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) to disavow any rep from it but left it in place, since I didn't want to just delete it after spending effort to write it.
5. [Is urlencode & urldecode is sufficient for URL attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530477/is-urlencode-urldecode-is-sufficient-for-url-attacks) This close seems dubious to me in hindsight.
   While the linked [semi-canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205889/how-to-prevent-code-injection-attacks-in-php) is certainly relevant, it's not really a duplicate.  I should probably vote to reopen this one.
6. [How to open a .txt.enc file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615578/how-to-open-a-txt-enc-file) Answered and voted to migrate to [SU](https://superuser.com), but other voters disagreed and the question ended up closed but not migrated.
7. [PAR::Packer trouble with included files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273604/parpacker-trouble-with-included-files) Looks like I originally voted to close this as a dupe, but the OP commented that they didn't find the answers to [the suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125689/where-does-pp-par-unpack-add-a-files) helpful, so I answered their question directly.  I should probably have retracted my close vote, but that [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) was still kind of new and I probably wasn't familiar with it yet.  In any case, the question eventually accumulated five close votes and was marked as a dupe.  Not quite sure what to do with it now.
8. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714881/if-im-passing-input-101011-from-s-box-2-of-des-then-what-should-be-the-answer It looks like I answered this one, but the (trivial) answer went straight over the OP's head.  Maybe there was a language issue or something, but I think I eventually voted to close the question as "unclear what you're asking".  Given the marginal topicality of this question, I should probably just delete my answer and let this one be roomba'ed, too.

---

<sup>Ps. One reason for this test was that I'd been thinking of requesting a feature that would prevent users from answering a question that they had a pending close vote on, and vice versa.  Before doing that, though, I wanted to see if there might be any cases where I'd have personally found such a feature counterproductive.</sup>

<sup>Based on reviewing the eight questions above, my cautious evaluation is that most of them would've been fine under such a rule.  In some cases I would've had to retract my close vote in order to answer (many of those questions are from before that feature was added) or delete my answer in order to close-vote, but in most cases that would've been OK.</sup>

<sup>The trickiest cases (#1 and #6) above are related to migrations, which I feel are [kind of problematic in general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309554).  While [the FAQ advises against migrating answered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250), in my experience it can be harder to get *un*answered questions migrated (because mods don't like migrating stuff that they're not sure will get a good answer), and in any case telling somebody that "I know the answer to your question, but you'll need to repost it on this other site (or wait a day or two to get it moved there) before I'll tell you what it is" feels like kind of an asshole thing to do.  That said, as long as mod-flagging questions one has answered remains possible, I don't see any major issues with not being able to close-vote them.  The close-vote-to-migrate path is IMO pretty broken anyway (except for main-to-meta migrations, which it handles quite well).</sup>

<sup>The cross-site version of the query also turns up a bunch of meta questions, most of them bug reports or feature requests that I'd answered and later voted to close as "no longer reproducible" after the reported issue had been quietly fixed or made irreproducible by other changes.  Arguably, the problem here is with that particular oddball close reason, but a simple workaround would be to just exempt meta sites from the can't-answer-and-close-vote rule, if such a rule were to be implemented.  Meta sites are special in many other ways, anyway.</sup>

Comment: This is a related (only dupe hammer) FR https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355334/5292302, anyway very nice query, it's time or all us to do some clean up of non useful Q/A's and for sure you don't fit the "pattern" logic.

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing sounds like abuse that should be stopped.  But there are innocent ways that you can end up with an answer and a close-vote.

I sometimes answer and vote to migrate (e.g. to superuser).  But usually people vote to close as "should have been asked on SU", rather than voting to migrate, which leaves it closed on SO with my name as one of the close voters.

This happened today with [Was there a 'git' in the 1990s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777487/was-there-a-git-in-the-1990s).  I answered it because it was somewhat interesting, and I knew the answer.

After having my answer half-finished, I noticed a comment on the question pointing out that it wasn't really on topic for SO, even though it was interesting and not inherently a bad question.  I posted an answer anyway, expecting that we could get the question migrated if there is anywhere else on stackexchange it might belong.  (It's not a great fit for Superuser either.)

Then I voted to migrate to Superuser, and left a comment encouraging others to do the same.  This is done by voting to close as "belongs on another site"->Superuser.  The majority of the close voters voted "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming", which is a separate close reason, so the question is still on SO but closed.

(And apparently very unpopular, with 7 downvotes and 3 upvotes, so probably not worth trying to do anything with it.  The info is easy to find on wikipedia anyway, so I'm not upset about this particular question doing down the drain.)

---

For questions that are definitely worth keeping, I've sometimes (like 2 or 3 times over the last 3 years) raised a custom mod flag to ask for migration if it looks like people are going to close it instead of migrate it.  (Or if that's already happened).

Maybe that's selfish of me, but I'd rather just answer it while I'm already thinking about the question itself (rather than moderating the question), instead of waiting until it maybe gets re-asked on another site and then having to find it or wait for someone to ping me about it.  Sometimes it's not obvious where to draw the line with computer-architecture questions, so I don't feel the need to punish someone for asking https://superuser.com/questions/1226197/x86-address-space-controller on SO instead of SU.

If it happened a lot, I wouldn't burden the moderators with it.  (Usually people that ask interesting questions choose the right site, and I don't want to answer boring questions anyway.)

Comment: Actually…I think that question might be a better fit for [Retrocomputing.SE] than Super User. Update: convinced myself and [migrated it](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4519/was-there-a-git-in-the-1990s). If they close it there, we'll know I was wrong, but I think it's an interesting question, has a good answer, and deserves a good home. Git itself may not be retro, but asking about DCS in the mid-90s certainly seems to qualify.