# Suggestion for the 'Flagging Move to Another Site NotListed'-Problem

Tags: discussion, flags

As I got the reputation to start reviewing on SO, I stumbled upon the problem that there are questions which belong to other sites on the StackExchange network but when flagging them as Off-topic --> Belong to another site, the site where the questions should be asked on is not listed.

I know that I, as a frequent SO user, don't know what is appropriate on other sites and blindly voting to move a question to a particular site on the SE network is not resposible. I am also aware of [this question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options).

Nevertheless, I think that this problem needs to be addressed and therefore thought that a possible solution would be to include a little wizard in the flagging dialog that asks simple questions about the question and then guides the user to the appropriate SE site.

What do you think about that?

Comment: 'I think that this problem needs to be addressed': disagree.  It sounds like free outsorcing of work that the OP's should have done in the first place.  'simple questions about the question and then guides the user' I'm not convinced that is possible.  Each SE site has it's own rules and policies, and there is only one user that should be reading them and making decisions on where to post.

Comment: I know that it one should do the research when asking a question, but many new users simply don't know that SO might not be the appropriate place to ask. I therefore think that it's our task to guide them through appropriate comments and flags, but we cannot guide them without being properly guided ourselves

Comment: @vatbub wizard? Yes, maybe. To be shown to the flaggers? No. To be shown to the poster? Yes, maybe. Why should we do their work and hope they learn to.... Not rely on that in the future?

Comment: This is already part of the new question wizard. Do a search for "wizard" here on meta.

Comment: I also think that it's the poster's task to do the research, but with the current solution, I often find myself simply googling "some other subject stack exchange" to give the poster at least a hint about where he should have probably posted his question. I don't always have the time to properly verify whether that question would be appropriate on that site and would therefore be grateful for a little wizard that would help me out.

Comment: @TinyGiant But people still post off-topic stuff on SO, hence, I don't think that the current wizard is very effective

Comment: @vatbub I think you need to do a bit of research before making a statement like that. The wizard is an ongoing project currently in development.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that a wizard that asks some simple questions about the question then guides the user to the appropriate SE site would be very effective for several reasons.

1. When requesting migration, you should be familiar enough with the site you are migrating to to know if it will be on topic there. If someone is already familiar enough with the site to know that the question is a good fit, then they can request the migration to one of the 5 pre-approved sites in our flag list, or make [a custom moderator flag explaining why the question is on topic on the site you want to move it to.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options#comment63599_251654)
2. Adding enough questions to overcome that previous obstacle of needing to know about it would result in a lot of questions. Let's say someone posts a cooking question here, and you think it looks like a decent question but have no idea what's allowed on the Cooking Stack Exchange. The wizard will have to ask you "Is your question about Cooking & food preparation methods, Kitchen equipment, Food handling and storage, Ingredient selection and use, Recipe comprehension, improvement, and repairs, or The history of food and cooking?" then when they pick, to outline the subsets of not-allowed things, say if they want to ask about Recipe Comprehension: "Is this a question about Recipe swapping?" which is off topic, and so forth for each one. Think of the answer tree that would be generated by this for a user unfamiliar with the site to make sure that their question is actually on topic.
3. And if just figuring out if the question is on topic for that specific site or not results in a lot of questions, think about the number of questions we would need to distinguish between the **174** (currently) Stack Exchange sites. It'll take a lot of questions to narrow that down. So I guess the point of these points (2) and (3) is that there is no simple list of questions that you could ask in a wizard to get things to the right site and make sure they're on topic there.
4. It's not really our problem. We're forgiving and migrate the questions that appear that they might be on topic for Stack Overflow by someone who doesn't really understand that Stack Overflow is specifically for programming questions and asks about some tech questions to their proper site if they can't get an answer here. However, the sites we migrate to are the ones that can be easily mistaken for being on topic here, like Data Base Administration questions, or Tex/LaTeX questions, or Super User questions that don't have to do with programming. But if someone is posting a question here and it doesn't belong here, that's not our fault and not our responsibility to get it where it belongs. We only do it with some sites because we're nice people.
5. If we were to do this, then people might start to treat Stack Overflow as a catch-all type site. "Don't know which Stack Exchange site your question is on topic for? Just post it to Stack Overflow, they'll migrate it to the site where it belongs for you." Yeah, I don't want us being known for being the Triage of the Stack Exchange Network, since we already know how well our [own triage works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326666/whats-the-mods-policy-on-incorrect-edit-reviews?noredirect=1&lq=1).
6. Something really really useful about people getting frustrated about only having 5 sites to migrate to is that users who want to migrate somewhere else search for the reason why we only allow 5, and are met with lots of guidance regarding migrations, most importantly, to [not migrate crap](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309554/7795130). Many of the rejected migration flags are simply because somebody sees a question and thinks that since it's about a subject of another site, it should go there, regardless of the quality. When users are unable to flag to very many sites and go to find out why, they become more educated about what to flag for migration and when to do it.
7. We only permit flagging for migration to sites where we have a decent record of successful migrations to that site, and that reasoning has already been thoroughly discussed in the [Flagging for Migration should include more options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options) question.

Comment: Educating users is a valid point, but then, shouldn't we educate users in place rather than having them come over to Meta? Also, I don't think that we need to cover _all_ sites and every detail of every site. Noone is going to ask a cooking question on SO, however, there are many questions about computer related stuff which don't belong on SO nor on any of the other listed sites.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't think about the wizard as a replacement for the Triage queues and I don't think of it as a complete replacement, just a tool to help guiding users

Comment: Well you never know, someone who doesn't know anything about the Chef programming language and takes things way too literally and sees [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19148995/7795130) might misunderstand and think it belongs on the Cooking stack exchange ;)

Comment: Okay, so I was just trying to be funny with the example of Cooking, but the point is if people just see Stack Overflow as a "general computer question site," then they 1) Haven't read the tour 2) Haven't looked at the asking guide in the help pages, and 3) Haven't read the yellow box with big bold **Is your question about programming?** notes when you ask a question. So their question is just as off topic as a cooking question, and they've had plenty of opportunities to educate themselves.

Comment: I guess a better comparison could have been if I put one for the Law Stack Exchange, because some people actually do ask questions about the legality of certain things or about licensing, which might be about something the user wants to program, so they think that it goes here, even though Licensing questions are actually off-topic, as are most legal questions here on SO. A user might want to migrate this SO question to the Law Stack Exchange, but it would still take several questions just for the Wizard to evaluate if the question is actually appropriate there. Same issue as above.